# Web Service Response XML retrieve 'DestinationUnreachable' Message

Tags: wcf

I am getting the following message in Response XML while processing Request XML in SoapUI tool.We have got the same message for all types of services associated with Application.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
   <s:Header>
      <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/soap/fault</a:Action>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body>
      <s:Fault>
         <s:Code>
            <s:Value>s:Sender</s:Value>
            <s:Subcode>
               <s:Value>a:DestinationUnreachable</s:Value>
            </s:Subcode>
         </s:Code>
         <s:Reason>
            <s:Text xml:lang="en-US">The message with To '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher.  Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree.</s:Text>
         </s:Reason>
      </s:Fault>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Anyone has any idea what we should do to resolve this issue?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 26):

Issue is because the Request message is missing a To header.
On the Message Editor, just below the request message window click on button WS-A.
Then select the checkbox "**Add default wsa:To**

Now run your request and the service will run just fine.

Hope that helps

Comment: Is this supported with Azure APIM?

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you posted the request XML (and also the relevant parts of the WSDL), but by the looks of it it's an addressing issue. Check that you're using the same SOAP version on the client and server (1.1 vs. 1.2), that the usage of WS-Addressing is consistent, etc. Also, try generating a WCF client (with svcutil / Add Service Reference), send a message using that client, capture it (e.g. using Fiddler), and - assuming it works - compare it to the message generated by SoapUI.